# Good practices for audit data changes for SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, audit, change-tracking

In my current project we are required to keep the records of data changes for the Employee table at least for specific field for NOW (it can be extended for all the fields later).

We are also required to populate all the historical changes for each employee in Employee View screen by default, where we need to show the **OLD and NEW values**.

We are thinking for following two approach.

Having History table for Employee with Same schema along with few additional columns. This can be filled either using **Triggers or via SPs used for CURD operations**. (which one is good Triggers or SPs?)

or

We can have common table with basic schema like follow
**TableName,FieldName,ChangeBy,ChangeDT,OldValue,NewValue** etc..

Application is being developed in ASP.NET CORE with MSSQL2016.

Which one should be preferred or please share the best alternative.

Comment: Have you considered using Temporal Tables?   New feature in 2016.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: *For what purpose* do you need to track changes? Is it for legal/auditing purposes, reporting purposes? Will you need to be able to read/report the changes frequently or just in case of an incident? Is there a permission aspect?

Comment: @Daniel, yes, we need to track the changes for auditing and reporting purpose. changes made by any admin users should be displayed with old and new.

Comment: @Jonathan, We saw few limitations of temporal hence we drop the idea.